# Line formed by using underscore symbol in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I unknowingly created a horizontal line using underscore symbol in MS-Word, help me to delete this horizontal line from the document

Comment: Press the Delete button =\

Answer (score 2):

That option does not work. 
I had the same problem and couldn't solve it that way - the line created from multiple underscore hits can't be highlighted on. It creates a border. To resolve thus, head over to Borders and simply select 'No Border'.

Answer (score 1):

The underscores are just characters like any other you might have typed and hence can be deleted in the same way as any other character. For instance, you can ...

- Click at the start of the line and repeatedly press the `Del` key
- Click at the end of the line and repeatedly press the `Backspace` key
- Select the whole line (by dragging the mouse from beginning to end, or by right-clicking at the left border of the line) and then click `Del` or `Backspace` just once.

Answer (score 0):

Select border's above and Border's below Text line.

Then go to Home menu Border selection type "No Border".
Or use the keyboard sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>.